# Nuget Command Line Update is trying to change my readonly csproj file

Tags: jenkins, project, nuget

I am new to Nuget and relatively new to Jenkins. I am attempting to have Jenkins run this command "nuget update XXX.sln  -Verbose -RepositoryPath packages -Source wwww.hatever/nuget/" to check to see if there are any updates to a referenced nuget package and update that reference if there is a newer version.

The problem I am having is that nuget tries to update the hintpath to the reference in my csproj file but errors out because the csproj file is checked into TFS and is readonly. We use TFS in Jenkins to get the latest changes so I have to keep the csproj file as readonly.

Is there a way to get nuget to update my reference via the nuget update command without having to change the hintpath in my csproj file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update the individual project's NuGet packages by using below command :
nuget update $(projdir)\packages.config -RepositoryPath ..\Packages  -Source xx

This would just update the references in the packages folder without touching the csproj file.